# Javascript code - Generate random text from seperate word buckets based on drop down list inner text

Tags: javascript, random

```
var e = document.getElementById("select_list"); //drop down list
var textselected= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; //selected text by user

var Select1 = [ //random text picker 1
  "Text1",
  "Text2",
  "Text3",
];

var Select2 = [ //random text picker 2
  "Text1",
  "Text2",
  "Text3",
];

var Select3 = [ //random text picker 3
  "Text1",
  "Text2",
  "Text3",
];

$("#click-button").click(function() { //button to pick random text

if (textselected.includes('textselected1')) { //if user selected 1 then 
$("#quote-box p").html(Select1[Math.floor(Math.random()*Select1.length)]);

 } else if (textselected.includes('textselected2')) {   
 $("#quote-box p").html(Select2[Math.floor(Math.random()*Select2.length)]);   


} else if (textselected.includes('textselected3')) {   
 $("#quote-box p").html(Select3[Math.floor(Math.random()*Select3.length)]);   

  }
});
```

I have a drop down list in website with ID = 'select_list'
Basically when user selecting something then the selection inner text will need to be used as a criteria for random text qoutes.

I have three items in drop down list named: textselected1, textselected2, textselected3

If user selected 'textselected1' then when button clicked random text will be generated in 'quote-box' from random text list 'Select1'

If user selected 'textselected2' then same button clicked but random text will be generated in 'quote-box' will be from random text list 'Select2' etc..

Please need some help with the code as I started to write something but it doesnt work.

Any help will be much apprieciated.

Comment: Please show what you have written and explain the problems with it, we will then help with fixing that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these lines

```
`var e = document.getElementById("select_list");
var textselected= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;`
```

to click handler function like these

```
`$("#click-button").click(function() {
var e = document.getElementById("select_list");
var textselected= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

if (textselected.includes('textselected1')) {    
$("#quote-box p").html(Select1[Math.floor(Math.random()*Select1.length)]);`
```